# repo cloned from one remote branch needs to be commited to a different remote branch

Tags: mercurial

We have a master repository located on a separate server. I originally cloned the default branch and made my changes locally. I have locally commited those changes. However, there has been a branch created on the master repository that I would like to push my changes to. Below is the description of my attempt at getting this accomplished.

I have cloned the branch. I am trying to export my changes from local default like so:

```
C:\hg\default>hg export -g -o mypatch -r tip
```

and when trying to import them into the clone of the new branch, I get the following:

```
C:\hg\newBranch>hg import C:\hg\default\mypatch
applying C:\hg\Fill1\mypatch
patching file .hgignore
Hunk #1 FAILED at 11
1 out of 1 hunks FAILED -- saving rejects to file .hgignore.rej
abort: patch failed to apply
```

I can manually fix the .hgingore.rej file just fine. The problem is that the patch also contains files that were moved. Instead of the files showing as moved, I get the following when running `hg status`:

```
C:\hg\newBranch>hg status -C
M someOtherFilesThatLookAsExpected.txt
! originalLocaion\fileA.txt
? newLocation\fileA.txt
```

This missing and new status is for all files that were moved in the commit contained the applied patch. Am I doing something wrong? Do I always have to manually move files when applying a patch? Is there an easier way to accomplish this branch transfer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a bit difficult to answer without knowing more about your repository structure, but here's how I'd go about it without knowing more. I'm assuming that the reason for the conflict is that there are conflicting changes in the same branch of the repository.

First, get the contents of the newBranch repository:

```
cd c:\hg\default
hg pull c:\hg\newBranch
```

Then, either merge or rebase your changes on top. If you are working on the same branch, then just using

```
hg pull --rebase c:\hg\newBranch
```

in lieu of the regular pull should do (assuming you have rebasing enabled). Otherwise, do an explicit merge or rebase of the two heads that you need to reconcile. Finally, do:

```
hg push -r tip c:\hg\newBranch
```

in order to get your (now reconciled) changes back into newBranch.

Unless you have very specific and unusual requirements, `push` and `pull` should be your normal way to sync repositories or part of them (note that using -r will only push/pull the respective branch). Export/import are rather low-level mechanisms that may not give you the benefits of the standard machinery that handles renames, three-way merging logic, etc.

Comment: I don't see `--rebase` when I run `hg help pull`

Comment: when you say `hg pull c:\hg\newBranch` am i supposed to do `C:\hg\default>hg pull c:\hg\newBranch`?

Comment: rebase is only enabled if you turn on the rebase extension (which is not enabled by default because it can modify history). You may or may not want it if you aren't comfortable with rewriting history. And yes, cd to c:\hg\default directory before pulling.